# Draggable windows forms bar

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I am making a windows forms app just to test out my designing skills, but I find that the outline is ugly, so I made my own Minimise and Close buttons, but I'm not sure how to make a pannel that you can drag around. Can anyone help me?

By the way, the code is C#.

Comment: C# / VB? please clarify your question.

Comment: The code is C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using events we can take the current location when we leftclick (MouseDown) and on MouseMove, we take the current window location minus where we were before and add the distance we've dragged our mouse.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    private Point windowLocation;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.windowLocation = e.Location;

    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // Refers to the Form location (or whatever you trigger the event on)
            this.Location = new Point(
                (this.Location.X - windowLocation.X) + e.X, 
                (this.Location.Y - windowLocation.Y) + e.Y
            );

            this.Update();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I will try this, thank you for your help!